# I can't pass a parameter to the "product" and so I can't give my get(id)"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to pass the parameter of my item to be able to give the "get(id)". But I'm not getting it, this parameter has to come from the index page when I click on the details on the item. If I put a number to give the get, it goes and returns the json of the item, but I can't print it on the screen either.

**EDIT2:**
I already managed to solve the parameter, I updated my code but I can't return my product to the page, it's giving the same error in the edit.

```
public async Task<Product> GetOne(ProductInsert product)
{  
        ProductInsert produto = new ProductInsert()
        {
            sku = product.sku
        };

        var client = new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("https://test.testla.com.br")
        };

        string jsonObjeto = JsonSerializer.Serialize(produto.sku);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-user-email", "victor@test.com.br");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-store-key", "1");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/app/Api/V1/Products/" + produto.sku);

        // string jsonObjeto = JsonSerializer.Serialize(produtoCriado);
        req.Content = new StringContent("Content-type", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using var res = await client.SendAsync(req);
        //res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Rootobject>(responseBody);
        var output = new List<Product>();
        root?.result.data.ToList().ForEach(x => output.Add(x.product));

        return null;
}
```

My controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Data.Entity;
using WebConsumoApi.Interfaces;
using WebConsumoApi.Models;

namespace WebConsumoApi.Controllers
{
    public class ProdutosController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IProduto _IProduto;

        public ProdutosController(IProduto IProduto)
        {
            _IProduto = IProduto;
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            var products = await _IProduto.ListAsync(); 
            return View(products);
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(ProductInsert product)
        {
            var products = await _IProduto.GetOne(product);

            return View(products);
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ProductInsert collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Create(collection);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(ProductInsert product)
        {
            return View(_IProduto.GetOne(product));
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, Product collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Update(collection);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: ProdutosController/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(ProductInsert product)
        {
            return View(_IProduto.GetOne(product));
        }

        // POST: ProdutosController/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(string id, Product collection)
        {
            try
            {
                _IProduto.Delete(id);
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My details view (`Get(Id)`):

```
@model WebConsumoApi.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Product</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sku)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.sku)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.status)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.status)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.qty)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.qty)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.price)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.list_price)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.list_price)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_gross)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.weight_gross)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.weight_liquid)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.weight_liquid)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.height)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.height)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.width)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.width)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.length)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.length)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.items_per_package)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.items_per_package)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.brand)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.brand)
        </dd>
        <dt class = "col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ean)
        </dt>
        <dd class = "col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ean)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.sku }) |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**

[image: ERROR]

**EDIT 3:**

MY JSON:

```
{"success":true,"result":{"product":{"sku":"GG005","name":"Gabinete Gamer","description":"Gabinete Gamer com RGB","status":"enabled","qty":15,"price":399.9,"list_price":399.9,"weight_gross":0.3,"weight_liquid":0.25,"height":9,"width":3,"length":5,"items_per_package":"1","brand":"Mr. Cat","ean":null,"ncm":null,"categories":[{"code":null,"name":null}],"images":["https:\/\/manairadigitalteste.conectala.com.br\/app\/assets\/images\/product_image\/DCA2235E-B4B5-23C9-7BEF-0A3581DD2433\/16587766584120.jpg"],"variation_attributes":["UN"]}}}
```

Comment: I'm returning null just to try to solve the problems above in the code, such as receiving a parameter and being able to deserialize the object. After I resolve it I will return something.

Comment: `res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();` should not be commented. If there's an error, the exception will be thrown.

Comment: I uncommented the line and gave the same error. It gives the error when it arrives at the line "root?.result.data.ToList().ForEach(x => output.Add(x.product));". And another doubt "res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();" what does it do?

Comment: It checks the status code of the result and make sure the code is success (2xx). You should check `responseBody` to see if the result returned correctly.

Comment: //GET: ProdutosController/Edit/5
public ActionResult Edit([FromQuery] int id)

Comment: My responseBody is returning the json correctly, I'm just having problems when finishing the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
public class Category
{
    public object code { get; set; }
    public object name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string sku { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double list_price { get; set; }
    public double weight_gross { get; set; }
    public double weight_liquid { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int length { get; set; }
    public string items_per_package { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
    public object ean { get; set; }
    public object ncm { get; set; }
    public List<Category> categories { get; set; }
    public List<string> images { get; set; }
    public List<string> variation_attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Product product { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

//C# Code - 

var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(responseBody);
return root.Result.Product;
```

Comment: I've already managed to receive my parameter quietly otherwise just like I said in the edit. I'm having problems finishing the method, I can't display the product on the screen.

Comment: you should check whether the response JSON is parsed correctly into RootObject or not..

Comment: My Rootobject is returning correctly, but I can't extract the product from it. The "product" comes in the rootobject json.

Comment: you can share a sample JSON to validate

Comment: I put in edit 3 my json. The attributes that my Rootobject returns are: "offset, "result" and "sucess". In my method of listing all products, my method works with this line "root?.result.data.ToList().ForEach(x => output.Add(x.product));". Already in the listing of only one product it is not working.

Comment: you can update data types as per your need. JSON doesn't have a list of products it contains only product object

Comment: In my listing method it worked like this, because I listed the rootobject, as it is just an item, how can I do it?

Comment: I have already shared the classes. you can use that